# Is there any way to allow selection of minimum 2 day in bootstrap daterangepicker?

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker for date range selection. but the problem is that I need to set the end date minimum 1 day advance to startdate. enddate should be the same as startdate.
can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: If the options are same day or next day, do you even need a date range picker? It sounds like a single date picker for start date with a dropdown or radio selection of same/next day for end date would simplify the issue and be clearer for your users.

Comment: User can select any date range, but minimum two days should be allowed